# add dynamic row on click of a button with some values cell empty using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have designed a table with a row having textbox, drop-down, some contents and a button. The values are actually taken from the database and displayed using php. When I click on the button it should replicate the last row of the table with the button again if I click on the button of the dynamic row the same thing should happen. I tried the following code but not working, the code is working if I put the button outside the table.

I used even on() instead of live(), its not working, please help

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table id=`tableid`>
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="row1"></td><td>
    <select><option>Apple</option><option>Mango</option></select>
     </td><td><button id='buttonid'>Add Row</button></td><td>content1</td><td>content2</td></tr>
     </table>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
       $( "#buttonid" ).live( "click",  function(){
      var cnt = $('#tableid tr:last').clone();
      cnt.find('td:nth-last-child(2)').empty(); //Last but one td
      cnt.find('td:nth-last-child(1)').empty(); //Last td
      $('#tableid').append(cnt);
      });

      });
      </script></body></html>
```

Comment: do you only have one `tr`?

Comment: Here is a similar [example](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/277xQ/). See if this helps.

Comment: @karan3112 `add` doesn't work for dynamic elements here.

Comment: Here is the updated [link](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/277xQ/2/). Use `$(document).on()`

Comment: the example is working on live, if I copy paste and run on local its not working

Answer (score 0):

- dut to cloning, `button` should have class, not id.

  ```
  <button class='button'>
  ```
- for dynamic elements you can use

  ```
  $(document).on("click", ".button", function()
  {
      //your code
  });
  ```
- **EDIT:** as [sabithpocker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427146/sabithpocker) mentioned, it is also important to replace

  ```
  <table id=`tableid`>
  ```

  with

  ```
  <table id="tableid">
  ```

[Fiddle with this](http://jsfiddle.net/tgbm9zLn/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="tableid">
```

not

```
<table id=`tableid`>
```

Not sure what is not working for you http://jsfiddle.net/76d1gj0L/

Comment: @Regent yes, `live` got replaced with `on` but I saw OP is using `jQuery v1.11.0` . Just wanted to point out that this may be the reason why his code is not working. We cant teach everything in one answer :)

Comment: Well, yes, it's definitely the reason, because `.live()` was removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: @Regent Ohh, yes... I had in mind that `1.11` is some very old version when I saw lot of `1` :)

Answer (score 0):

You should traverse from its parent which will not change, as you are removing the button and append it after clicking it.

i.e

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tableid" ).on( "click", "#buttonid",  function(){
    var cnt = $('#tableid tr:last').clone();
    cnt.find('td:nth-last-child(2)').empty(); //Last but one td
    cnt.find('td:nth-last-child(1)').empty(); //Last td
    $('#tableid').append(cnt);
  });
 });
```

But this won't work after first click, as `id` should be unique for every element, so instead of having the `id` attribute on the button, use the `class` attribute.

```
<table id='tableid'>
 <tr><td><input type="text" name="row1"></td><td>
 <select><option>Apple</option><option>Mango</option></select>
 </td><td><button class='buttonid'>Add Row</button></td><td>content1</td><td>content2</td></tr>
 </table>
```

And javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#tableid" ).on( "click", ".buttonid",  function(){
    var cnt = $('#tableid tr:last').clone();
    cnt.find('td:nth-last-child(2)').empty(); //Last but one td
    cnt.find('td:nth-last-child(1)').empty(); //Last td
    $('#tableid').append(cnt);
  });
 });
```

Comment: You wrote `$("#tableid" ).on( "#buttonid", "click",` instead of `$("#tableid" ).on("click", "#buttonid"` and `$("#tableid ).live(  "click", ".buttonid",` instead of `$("#tableid ).on(  "click", ".buttonid",`

Comment: And now you have `$("#tableid" ).on( "click", "#buttonid"` instead of `$("#tableid" ).on( "click", ".buttonid"` in second script :)

Comment: its not working after giving the class instead of id

Comment: @Xlander it works indeed. Maybe OP doesn't fix problem with table id quotes.

Comment: Sorry but what is 'OP'?

Comment: @Xlander you forgot to add '@Regent' to your comment - so I wasn't notified about your comment. "OP" is "Original Poster" - the author of question. You can see this term in [glossary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)